# How to arrange icons on desktop in KDE

Tags: kde, desktop, icons

I'm using KDE, my display manager is KDM:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/kdm
```

How do I arrange icons, or better to say - align them to a grid, on a KDE desktop on Debian?

I mean similar function as is on Windows (align icons to grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop > Default Desktop Settings > View. Change *Layout* to *Grid Desktop*.